# Installing ferret and acts_as_ferret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ferret, acts-as-ferret

I'm looking for a solid walkthrough or some direction on getting ferret set up on my rails server. Everyone on the internet makes it seem so easy, but I can't seem to get it all together.

What I've done succesfully:

```
gem install ferret
gem install acts_as_ferret
```

No sweat. No errors.

What doesn't work:

```
Video.find_by_content('test')
-----No Method Error
```

or
    ActsAsFerret.find('test', 'my_index')

I get console to recognize the constant "ActsAsFerret"(only when I install the plugin from https://github.com/jkraemer/acts_as_ferret), but find() returns a No Method Error.
**Update:** Installing the plugin like this also prevents Mongrel from starting

I AM running in development mode, but configured ferret_server.yml to know what's up.

So does any one have any suggestions? And has anyone had more luck using acts_as_ferret as a gem or as a plugin? Googling gets me small scraps and parts of tutorials that don't seem to fit together, so I hereby vow to blog a solution to this when I figure it out.

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

rails (3.0.3)

**P.S.** I also ran

```
sudo apt-get install ferret
```

on someone's suggestion... still no luck. I'm not even sure if that'd be a reasonable solution for deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you added

```
gem 'ferret'
gem 'acts_as_ferret'
```

in your Gemfile and run

```
bundle install
```

?

Comment: I added config.gem 'acts_as_ferret', :version => '~> 0.4.8' to environment.rb as per instruction of the developer...

Comment: From  https://github.com/jkraemer/acts_as_ferret for Rails 3
gem 'acts_as_ferret', '>= 0.5'

Comment: And it Gemfile not config/environment.rb for Rails 3

Comment: Yeah I realized I was following Rails 2.x instructions, but did the Rails instructions for the same results...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find_with_ferret` method